# Using MySQL Command Line Client

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, mysql-workbench

I'm new in creating databases in MySQL. I've done creating tables in MySQL Workbench. Now I want to check the databases I've created using the MySQL Command Line Client. How should I do this? What should I type in the Command Line? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To see all databases:

```
show databases;
```

To switch to a specific database (note that the trailing `;` is *optional* here):

```
use databasename
```

To see the tables within the current database:

```
show tables;
```

To see the `create table` statement for a specific table:

```
show create table tablename;
```

To see other misc info about a specific table:

```
describe tablename;
```

Additionally, all kinds of other interesting meta information is contained within the `information_schema` database. You can `use information_schema` and explore those tables for a wealth of information about your databases.

Another useful trick in the MySQL command line console is to terminate your queries with `\G` instead of `;`. This causes output to be displayed all vertically rather than in a table, which is useful for tables that are wider than your screen display.